# What does "Site Type" mean when creating a Site in a Spring 20 Scratch Org?

Tags: force.com-sites, scratch-org, spring-20

I've been trying to test the changes to Guest User access in Spring 20. In doing so, I've created a scratch org on Spring 20 and tried to create a Site to test with. However, it comes with options that are both confusing and apparently undocumented.

I made my scratch org with a basic scratch org def:

```
{
  "orgName": "Spring-20-Guest-Test",
  "country": "GB",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "Sites"
  ]
}
```

Then I went to Sites in the setup UI and clicked "New". At which point it asks me to choose the Site Type as either "Guest User License" or "Guest":

[image: Select Site Type Question]

What do these mean? Which one is like a Site created prior to Spring 20 so that it represents a realistic test of what will happen to existing sites after the release?

Comment: The two different license types I've seen in the past, so I don't think it's a Spring 20 issue.  I don't remember off hand what the difference between the two were though